# I am unable to test my android application "Process finished with exit code 1073741819"

Tags: android, android-studio

I just started using android studio yesterday, i made a simple form activity but i can't run the emulator.

I get these error, when i press **Debug 'app'** button, i've googled it but none of the solutions worked for me.

[image: these errors]

```
- Emulator: Process finished with exit code - 1073741819 (0x0C0000005)
- Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
- Emulator: Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!
- Emulator: getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!
- Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
```

Android studio version: 3.0.1

Virtual device: Nexus 5 API 26

Comment: did you try to open your application on your phone?

Comment: @AlokGupta No, i'll try now

Comment: Please insert the text of the error messages instead of a screenshot. This makes it easier for us to read, and for others with the same error to find your question.

Comment: @AlokGupta I get 'No target device found' error when i try to debug my app with my phone, i've tried many possible solutions but they didn't work either.

Comment: @Luuklag inserting now